# Cant get scrollify.js to work?

Tags: html, wordpress, jquery-scrollify

I am trying to use scrollify.js on my single page website but cannot get it to work?

I have the following html, header.php for loading scrollify and my js in my custom.js file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance?

HTML

```
        <?php get_header(); ?>
        <div id="sections_all">
        <div id="section_1">
            <section class='section'>
                <div class="section-1-container">
                    <h1 id="section_1">
                        <span style='font-size: 20vh;'>Sell your old <br>Garrard</span>
                    </h1>
                    <h2 id="section_1">
                        Looking to sell your turntable? We buy your used Garrard 301 & 401 record players.
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div id="section_2">
            <section class='section'>
                <div class="section-2-container">
                    <!--<p class="contact-text">Contact Us</p>-->
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="66" title="Contact Us"]'); ?>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div id="section_3">
            <section class='section'>
                <div class="section-3-container">
                    <h1 id="section_3">
                        Sell your old turntable
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div id="section_4">
            <section class='section'>
                <div class="section-4-container">
                    <h1 id="section_4">
                        Sell your old turntable
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Header PHP

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" class="no-js">
            <head>

                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width">
                <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
                <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
                <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
                <title>SellGarrard301</title>
                <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-scrollify@1.0.17/jquery.scrollify.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-scrollify@1.0.17/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
                <?php wp_head(); ?>

            </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="container">
                        <header class="header-wrapper">
                            <p class="logo-text">Sell Garrard.com</p>
                            <div class="hamburger-helper">
                            <div id="menu-toggle">
                                <div id="hamburger">
                                  <span></span>
                                  <span></span>
                                  <span></span>
                                </div>
                                <div id="cross">
                                  <span></span>
                                  <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <nav class="menu-hide">
                                    <?php
                                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                                    'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
                                                    'container'      => '',
                                                    'container_class' => 'menu-hidden',
                                                    'menu_class'     => 'menu-hide',
                                                    'menu_id'     => 'header_menu',
                                                    ) );
                                            ?>
                            </nav>




                        </header>

        <!-- end of header start of main content -->
```

Custom JS function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $(function() {
      $.scrollify({
      section: ".section",

      });
 });

 });
```

All files and scripts are loaded when I check but I cannot find any information on how to get it to work?

UPDATED CONSOLE ERRORS:

```
                jquery.scrollify.js:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
                at jquery.scrollify.js:45
                at jquery.scrollify.js:47
            (anonymous) @ jquery.scrollify.js:45
            (anonymous) @ jquery.scrollify.js:47
            jquery.scrollify.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
                at jquery.scrollify.min.js:1
                at jquery.scrollify.min.js:1
            (anonymous) @ jquery.scrollify.min.js:1
            (anonymous) @ jquery.scrollify.min.js:1
            jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
            jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3860 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.scrollify is not a function TypeError: $.scrollify is not a function
                at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/sellgarrard/SellGarrard/wp-content/themes/SellGarrard301/JS/custom.js?ver=4.8.3:134:7)
                at j (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js?ver=4.8.3:2:26911)
                at Object.add [as done] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js?ver=4.8.3:2:27220)
                at n.fn.init.n.fn.ready (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js?ver=4.8.3:2:29326)
                at new n.fn.init (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js?ver=4.8.3:2:24411)
                at n (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js?ver=4.8.3:2:405)
                at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/sellgarrard/SellGarrard/wp-content/themes/SellGarrard301/JS/custom.js?ver=4.8.3:133:1)
                at mightThrow (http://localhost/sellgarrard/SellGarrard/wp-content/themes/SellGarrard301/JS/jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3583:29)
                at process (http://localhost/sellgarrard/SellGarrard/wp-content/themes/SellGarrard301/JS/jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3651:12) undefined
            jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3860
            process @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3655
            setTimeout (async)
            (anonymous) @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3689
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3317
            fireWith @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3447
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3455
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3317
            fireWith @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3447
            ready @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3920
            completed @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3930
            jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3869 Uncaught TypeError: $.scrollify is not a function
                at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js?ver=4.8.3:134)
                at j (jquery.js:3094)
                at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3140)
                at n.fn.init.n.fn.ready (jquery.js:3373)
                at new n.fn.init (jquery.js:2816)
                at n (jquery.js:76)
                at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js?ver=4.8.3:133)
                at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3583)
                at process (jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3651)
            (anonymous) @ custom.js?ver=4.8.3:134
            j @ jquery.js:3094
            add @ jquery.js:3140
            n.fn.ready @ jquery.js:3373
            n.fn.init @ jquery.js:2816
            n @ jquery.js:76
            (anonymous) @ custom.js?ver=4.8.3:133
            mightThrow @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3583
            process @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3651
            setTimeout (async)
            jQuery.readyException @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3868
            (anonymous) @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3888
            mightThrow @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3583
            process @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3651
            setTimeout (async)
            (anonymous) @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3689
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3317
            fireWith @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3447
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3455
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3317
            fireWith @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3447
            process @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3671
            setTimeout (async)
            (anonymous) @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3689
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3317
            fireWith @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3447
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3455
            fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3317
            fireWith @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3447
            ready @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3920
            completed @ jquery-3.2.1.js?ver=4.8.3:3930
```

Comment: Have you checked console for errors? I'd have thought you'd need to include jquery **first**, then scrollify

Comment: Further more, `I cannot find any information on how to get it to work` - Have you tried their site that lists everything including multiple examples? https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#methods

Comment: Hi yes I have looked everywhere?! At a loss! I have added the console errors if that helps?

Comment: can you post your header menu html here?

Comment: already have the html is header php above or do you want the output from developer?

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis How could you not think to post that massive error with 'scrollify' mention multiple times within it? How can you be 'at a loss' whilst knowing you have a huge error?

Comment: yes. output from developer

Comment: sorry was being a dumbass i had the sc ripts loading before the wp head tag so was loading too early, all working now! Thanks for the help in prompting errors, new to all this

Comment: at a loss in reference as how to rectify the error? You can have a huge error and know it but still be at a loss as of how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

header.php

remove

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-scrollify@1.0.17/jquery.scrollify.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-scrollify@1.0.17/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
```

Open footer.php

find

```
</body>
```

Add this directly above like so

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-scrollify@1.0.17/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Your problem is as I suggested, jQuery needs to load in on the page **first**, then load in scrollify. Making scrollify the very last thing to load in *should* resolve the issue. If not, then you need to do it the proper WP way by [enqueing the script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).